# fminbound for a simple equation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
def profits(q):
    range_price = range_p(q)
    range_profits = [(x-c(q))*demand(q,x) for x in range_price]
    price = range_price[argmax(range_profits)] # recall from above that argmax(V) gives 
                                           # the position of the greatest element in a vector V
                                           # further V[i] the element in position i of vector V
    return (price-c(q))*demand(q,price)

print profits(0.6)
print profits(0.8)
print profits(1)
0.18
0.2
0.208333333333
```

With `q` (being quality) in `[0,1]`, we know that the maximizing quality is `1`. Now the question is, how can I solve such an equation? I keep getting the error that either `q` is not defined yet (which is only natural as we are looking for it) or I get the error that some of the arguments are wrong.

```
q_firm = optimize.fminbound(-profits(q),0,1)
```

This is what I've tried, but I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-b0a80dc20a3d> in <module>()
----> 1 q_firm = optimize.fminbound(-profits(q),0,1)

NameError: name 'q' is not defined
```

Can someone help me out? If I need to supply you guys with more information to the question let me know, it's my first time using this platform. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you define `q`?

Comment: Nowhere, we need to optimize it for maximum profits.

Comment: @Forge Look above, sorry for not mentioning you earlier (I'm still a noob here).

Comment: You will need to define the variable `q` to run `q_firm = optimize.fminbound(-profits(q),0,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

fminbound needs a callable, while `profits(q)` tries to calculate a single value. Use

`fminbound(lambda q: -profits(q), 0, 1)`

Note that the lambda above is only needed to generate a function for negative profits. Better define a function for `-profits` and feed it to fminbound.

Better still, use minimize_scalar instead of fminbound.